# How to install stock app on custom rom?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, custom-roms, rom, samsung-galaxy-ace

I flashed a custom rom but I didn't like it's default Contacts app (I prefer the stock app).

How can I install the stock Contacts app in a custom rom?

BTW the ROM I have is [CM7-APOCALYPSE-FINAL](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1700749)

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy the desired app from your favorite ROM (the apk is usually in /system/app) to your destination phone and then install it normally.

Comment: This will probably not work because the stock apps relie on the custom stock Android Framework also. Sometimes there are ported versions though. You should check XDA-Developers! Good Luck

Comment: @wayback Some apps might, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Yup this didn't work.